# What resources are there for learning Romanian in accordance with the CEFR ability levels?

Tags: resource-request, exams, cefr, romanian

I've tried searching around but I've not been able to find any information about CEFR in relation to the Romanian language.

I was looking at the Wikipedia page for the [CEFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages) and I can see that there are different levels and that each level indicates what you should be able to do. Are there any books or websites that I can use to find out about the specific words and phrases for each level as well as exercises that I can do to prepare for each exam? Perhaps the information I need is linked to from that Wikipedia page somewhere but I cannot find it.

I'm not actually studying for an exam, but I would like to start studying for one and take one day. Does CEFR have it's own website?

Comment: http://www.languagetesting.com/find-a-test

Comment: http://www.coe.int/en/web/portfolio/home

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I have found that the key words for each CEFR level are much the same from one language to another.

In a pinch, I would first identify the words for a CEFR level in a more common language, say German or Italian, and then try to learn the corresponding Romanian words. I've tried (with limited success) to learn Romanian using Italian equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, another resource you can consider is Beginner Romanian (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnerromanian). It may not be CEFR accredited but it should be helpful to any beginner looking for an introduction to the commonly used Romanian words and phrases.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "CEFR accredited"?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I think they are saying that the app does not teach Romanian in accordance with the CEFR levels.